# Kubernetes cronjob missed two runs

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-cronjob, k8s-cronjobber

I have the schedule `*/7 * * * *` but today my cronjob missed two runs at 56mins past and 0mins past and then later ran at 4mins past after noticing an issue:

> Saw a job that the controller did not create or forgot

I can't see any logs in either the k8 scheduler or the k8 controller manager during the period of 56mins past.

During this period other cronjobs in the cluster were working fine.

What should I do to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the spec for the cronjob. If your concurrencyPolicy is set to FORBID, then if a job takes longer than the run frequency, it will skip it.

Comment: It isn't set to forbid.